# Is "else if" one whole or two separate keywords in Java?

Tags: java

I happen to read the practicing material for [SCJP](http://www.sun.com/training/certification/java/scjp.xml) certification, and I just tripped over a chapter of flow control et al, where they give the impression that "`else if`" is a keyword on its own. I have always thought that it was just a normal `else`, containing nothing but an `if` block, braces omitted.

So, which is it?

*Edit:* I'd like to emphasize that this question is more in the "pique my interest" category than the "serious business" one.

Comment: See also: http://stackoverflow.com/questions/637980/if-else-and-if-elseif

Answer (score 11):

Yes, they are two separate keywords—the [Java language specification](http://java.sun.com/docs/books/jls/) does not specify an `else if` keyword. It is actually, as the other posters here have said, an `if` statement contained inside of an `else` statement.

EDIT: A lot of training/educational materials seem to imply that `else if` is actually a keyword (and, indeed, it is usually treated as such), but I am inclined to think that this is more for the sake of clarity/simplicity, with the consequence of sacrificing accuracy.

Answer (score 6):

it would be two separate keywords indicated by the space between the two words.

Answer (score 6):

It actually says

```
else {
    if { ... }
}
```

Answer (score 3):

It's two keywords.

**else** may be followed by a block or a single statement.

in the case of **else if**. The statement is another **if** statement.

**Update**

It wouldn't hurt to mention that **else if** is a common style choice for deeply nested **if** statements and makes this situation much more readable than nesting. Unless I need the fall-through behaviour possible with the **switch** statement, I use **else if** instead.

Answer (score 1):

Two separate keywords I believe. But i'm positive you cannot have an **else** without an **if**.

[Java Lexical Structure](http://java.sun.com/docs/books/jls/third_edition/html/lexical.html#229308)

Comment: Are you seriously saying that you cannot have an else statement?  :P

Answer (score 1):

While some languages do have 'elsif', 'elseif', or 'else if' as a separate statement (somewhat like a 'case' statement), Java is not one of them.

Answer (score 0):

I'm no Java expert, but in C it's certainly defined as two different keywords, and Java stole pretty liberally from that part of C's syntax.

Regardless, outside of silly questions on exams, it won't ever make a difference in practice.  The effect is identical either way.

Comment: Yeah, I'm aware of the practical meaninglessness. For some strange reason, I want to know these kinds of irrelevant pieces of data.

Answer (score 0):

If you open your assembly with a debugger you'd recognise its an "if" statement.

Comment: Doesn't answer the question. Also meaningless. Assembly won't tell you what keywords were used in the source code,