# Counting the value and pasting in another sheet based on the Cases

Tags: vba, excel

I have sheet "BW" and another sheet "Result". The sheet result has an Table with the weeknumber in column A.

I wanted to look for the weeknumber in sheet "result" and if the weeknumber is the same as the Weeknumber in my sheet "BW" in column "AX" then , I would like to count the number of "1"  in the sheet "BW" in column "T" and "u".

But the problem is I have two cases for the counting of "1" in Column T and U

1. The column AA should not be equal to null.
2. The column Z should Contain "Ontime".

If these two case satisfies, then I would like to look into the column T and U and wount count for the 1 in the column.

I tried the code. But the case is not getting satisfied. Any lead would be helpful.

```
Sub results()

Dim i As Integer, j As Integer, cntT As Integer, cntu As Integer, ws As Worksheet
Set ws = Sheets("Result")
Sheets("BW").Select
For i = 2 To WorksheetFunction.CountA(ws.Columns(1))
cntT = 0
cntu = 0
If ws.Range("A" & i) = Val(Format(Now, "ww")) Then Exit For
Next i

For j = 5 To WorksheetFunction.CountA(Columns(50))

If ws.Range("AA" & i) <> "" And ws.Range("Z" & i) = "PSW Ontime" Then
ElseIf ws.Range("A" & i) = Range("AX" & j) And Range("T" & j) = 1 Then cntT = cntT + 1
ElseIf ws.Range("A" & i) = Range("AX" & j) And Range("U" & j) = 1 Then cntu = cntu + 1

Next j
If cntT <> 0 Then ws.Range("B" & i) = cntT
If cntu <> 0 Then ws.Range("C" & i) = cntu
If cntT + cntu <> 0 Then
ws.Range("D" & i) = cntT + cntu
ws.Range("E" & i) = cntT / (cntT + cntu)
ws.Range("F" & i) = cntu / (cntT + cntu)
End If

ws.Range("E" & i & ":F" & i).NumberFormat = "0%"
End If
End Sub
```

[image: This how my sheet "BW" look like. The first row is the column name reference. I would like to look for the column "aX" and then check for column "AA" and "Z" and then count the number of 1 in column T and U.]

[image: This is the sample of my sheet2, it has an table. so it looks for the weeknumber in my sheet "BW" and if it is 30, then paste the count values in the columns accordingly]

Could someone help me , how I can introduce this case in my code.

Comment: Change this ws.Range("Z" & i) = "PSW Ontime"  to Ucase(ws.Range("Z" & i)) = UCase("Ontime")

Check if that helps you

Comment: Or replace ws.Range("Z" & i) = "PSW Ontime" by Instr(Ucase(ws.Range("Z" & i)),Ucase("PSW Ontime") = True

Comment: You are using the If and Else If incorrectly, according to your logical problem

Comment: @nishitdey can you show me an sample how to use ?

Comment: @danieltakeshi how do I , Do it then ? any sample ?

Comment: https://stackoverflow.com/questions/637980/if-else-and-if-elseif When you use: If (condition 1) Then (action1) ElseIf (condition2) Then (action 2) [...] ElseIf(condition n) Then (action n) End If, you are not making what you want, which is just: If (condition1 And condition2 And [...] condition n) Then (actions) End If

Comment: @Jenny change the if condition in the code inside the  FOR LOOP

If ws.Range("AA" & i) <> "" And  Instr(Ucase(ws.Range("Z" & i)),Ucase("PSW Ontime") = True Then

Comment: @nishitdey I get an error in the loop, "next without for "

Comment: @nishitdey I solved and got the output :) thank you